# How to find all integral elements over a subring using Macaulay2?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, macaulay2

I have the following question about Macaulay2. How to find all integral elements over a subring?

What I mean is the following. Suppose $A$  is a subring of $B$. How can I find the following set?

$$L=\{x\in B : x \text{ is integral over }A\}$$

Here $B$ is a quotient of polynomial ring over rational numbers (e.g., $\mathbb Q[x,y]/(xy+x-1))$ and $A$ is a subring of $B$. I am also not sure how to declare a subring $A$ inside another ring.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: First you say that $A$ is a subring of $B$, then you say that $A$ is a quotient ring and $B$ is a subring. I am confused.

Comment: I mean A is a quotient ring e.g. $\mathbb{Q}[x,y,z]/(xyz-1)$ and $B$ is a subring of $A$ e.g. $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ inside $\mathbb{Q}[x,y,z]/(xyz-1)$.Is it clear now?

Comment: In this case, how can $A$ be a subring of $B$, as you write in paragraph 2?

Comment: Oh sorry.I mean A is a subring of B.I carelessly switched the role of A and B.I have edited the question now.Thabk you.